# Слово "изгаляться"

Tags: этимология

Слово "изгаляться" означает "издеваться". Но какова его этимология? Ведь не от "голый" же произошло...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не от голый, конечно. От глагола г**а**лить.
Правда глагол этот весьма многозначный, даже омонимичный.
Но как минимум одно из значений вполне подходит: смеяться. "Изгаляться" исходно означало "скалить зубы". Развитие современного значения, видимо, окказионально.
Но ещё интереснее, что современный арготизм "галимый", вполне подходящий по значению, никак, видимо, с этим "галить" не связано.